# Is 令人 necessary in 最令人满意. vs 最满意

Tags: vocabulary, phrase, comparison, sentence

This came from a native speaker : 在广州生活最令人满意的是这一点.
But if I formed the sentence myself, it probably would not include 令人 as in  在广州生活最满意的是这一点.

Google translated both are the same.

So, would my sentence mean the same for native speakers?

Comment: Seems there is not a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 在广州生活最满意的是这一点

Without 令人，we understand that the sentence omits 我.  在广州生活我最满意的是这一点.

With 令人，it generalizes that it can satisfy normal people, not just me.

Answer (score 1):

> 在广州生活最满意的是这一点
>
> 在广州生活最令人满意的是这一点

These sentences are correct and have similar meaning.

令人(滿意|失望|...etc) not only refers to a general idea but also to a personal opinion.

e.g.

Boss: 你這次報告最令人滿意的是內容完整。(That's the boss' opinion, others may not think so.)

If you say 在广州生活最令**我**满意的是这一点, which expresses exactly how I feel about living in 广州.